# Merge two rows if value is Nan in panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have tables as below

```
                   Error Code ID      Error Code              Description of  Error Code
0                                NaN      Value                                     NaN
1                     OE_ATO_IN_OPEN      16169      Order priced ATO cannot be entered
2                                NaN        NaN                when a security is open.
3                      e$dup_request      16198  Duplicate modification or cancellation
4                                NaN        NaN     request for the same trade has been
5                                NaN        NaN                            encountered.
6          TRD_CONT_MOD_NOT_ALLOWED      16231     Continuous session trades 
7       STR_PRO_PARTIVIPANT_INVALID      16233     Proprietary requests cannot be made
```

I want to convert it into

```
                   Error Code ID     Error Code Value        Description of  Error Code
1                     OE_ATO_IN_OPEN      16169      Order priced ATO cannot be entered               
                                                               when a security is open.
3                      e$dup_request      16198  Duplicate modification or cancellation
                                                    request for the same trade has been
                                                                           encountered.
6          TRD_CONT_MOD_NOT_ALLOWED      16231     Continuous session trades 
7       STR_PRO_PARTIVIPANT_INVALID      16233     Proprietary requests cannot be made
```

Missing index are just for understanding purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First forward filling missing values by `ffill` and then aggregate `join`:

```
c = ['Error Code ID', 'Error Code']
df[c] = df[c].ffill()
df = df.groupby(c).agg(' '.join).reset_index()
```

If want remove rows with missing values in `Description of  Error Code` column use:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Description of  Error Code'])
c = ['Error Code ID', 'Error Code']
df[c] = df[c].ffill()
df = df.groupby(c).agg(' '.join).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
                 Error Code ID Error Code  \
0               OE_ATO_IN_OPEN      16169   
1  STR_PRO_PARTIVIPANT_INVALID      16233   
2     TRD_CONT_MOD_NOT_ALLOWED      16231   
3                e$dup_request      16198   

                           Description of Error Code  
0  Order priced ATO cannot be entered when a secu...  
1                Proprietary requests cannot be made  
2                          Continuous session trades  
3  Duplicate modification or cancellation request...
```

Comment: It is working but there are few cases when I need merge nan value for all columns, then what to do ?